# How many Encounter Powers can I use during an Encounter?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

So, I have a lvl. 1 cleric! I have 1 Encounter power + the power of my deity + Healing Word.

But how do encounter powers work?

Either you can only use ONE power from the whole 'encounter' category during an encounter?

or

You can only use EACH power only once during an encounter?

Comment: What books do you have?

Comment: If you have the player's handbook, you should read the beginning of the classes chapter, which explains how powers work.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Reading the book was how I got confused! I thought that you could use each encounter power once per encounter, but when I read: "An encounter power can be used once per encounter. You need to take a short rest before you can use one again." WHat I understood was that I could only use 1 encounter power of the ones available to me, because my 'encounter' ability or magic or power needed to rest and THEN I could choose another power during another encounter...

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton Avandras Rescue, Perlors Radiance, Healing Word (which you can use 2 per encounter) and Divine Glow

Comment: @BrianBallsun-Stanton oh and I am an elf ^_^ Cleric Elf THANK YOU a lot for clarifying that up!!!! :D

Comment: @Eilleen Ah, I can see how you'd misread it that way. Also, Brian meant which D&D books, like the players handbook, but it sounds like you've told us which you have in your other question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each encounter power you have can be used, normally, once, save for healing word.

[Healing word](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1455) notes:

> Special: You can use this power twice per encounter, but only once per round.

Therefore, as a half-elven cleric (I'm skipping human for now), you get your racial encounter power usable once (until you can take a short rest), your cleric's level 1 encounter power usable once (until you can take a short rest), your cleric's channel divinity (once, even though there's a choice of two, because channel divinity says that you can only use one "channel divinity" per encounter), and your healing word (usable twice, because it says so.)

Honestly? I'd play an essentials cleric if the above seems too overwhelming. It was a real pain to learn when I was picking up 4e, and I don't envy you starting with one of the earliest classes written.